# Configure MongoDB connection pooling in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, connection-pooling

I am trying to connect to a MongoDB replica set through a Spring Boot application with read preference secondary. I want to configure idle static connections **only to secondary instance** that get created automatically on application startup. I am using MongoClient to connect to MongoDB.

I came across MongoClientOptions bean that an be passed while creating the MongoClient. MongoClientOptions provides a property 'minConnectionsPerHost'. This creates idle connections to all the hosts (both primary and secondary). My requirement is to create idle connections only to secondary instance.

```
@Bean
MongoClientOptions mongoClientOptions() {
    return MongoClientOptions.builder()
            .minConnectionsPerHost(10)
            .build();
}
```

Is there a way to configure it using MongoClientOptions bean or any alternative to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `minPoolSize` URI option to specify the minimum connection pool size for each server. This setting applies to all servers that the client is connected to.

I am not aware of any connection pool size knobs that selectively apply to a subset of the servers.